# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I'm facing this error:

```
`Unable to load properties file for MultiWordNet
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:660)
at org.itc.mwn.MysqlDictionary.<init>(MysqlDictionary.java:85)`
```

This is the property file that MysqlDictionary.java is trying to read:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------
#Properties file properties MultiWordNet API

#Hostname of the MySQL server
MWN_HOSTNAME=localhost

#User
MWN_USER=root

#Password
MWN_PASSWD=

#Database name
MWN_DB=wordnet

#Cache of entity 
CACHE_CAPACITY=1000
```

And,finally, this is the part where the code fails:

```
public MysqlDictionary() {
    try {
        connectionParameters = new Properties();
        connectionParameters.load(new FileInputStream(new File("./conf/multiwordnet.properties")));
    } catch (java.io.IOException ioee) {
        System.err.println("Unable to load properties file for MultiWordNet");
    }

    /// connection drivers instance
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        //Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException E){
        System.err.println("Unable to load driver");
    } catch(IllegalAccessException E){
        System.err.println("Unable to load driver");
    } catch(InstantiationException E){
        System.err.println("Unable to load driver");
    }

    // MultiWordnet db connection
    String  host = connectionParameters.getProperty("MWN_HOSTNAME");
    String user = connectionParameters.getProperty("MWN_USER");
    String passwd = connectionParameters.getProperty("MWN_PASSWD");
    String dbname = connectionParameters.getProperty("MWN_DB");
    Integer cache = new Integer(connectionParameters.getProperty("CACHE_CAPACITY"));  
    //here is where the parsing fails, but the file is properly written!
try {
        DEFAULT_CACHE_CAPACITY = cache.intValue();

        String conn = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + dbname;
        this.db = DriverManager.getConnection(conn,user,passwd);
        this.stmt = db.createStatement();


        System.err.println("Welcome to the MultiWordNet API\nConnection database ...OK\n");
    } catch (SQLException E) {
        System.out.println("Unable to establish multiwordnet Mysql DB connection on " + host + "(" + user + " - " + passwd + ")");
        E.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
```

The strange thing is that the program started suddenly failing, after it was running correctly

Comment: Are your sure that `connectionParameters` is been loaded correctly and contains all the values?

Comment: Do check you properties file, for the key: CACHE_CAPACITY, ensure the spelling in the file matches in your code

Comment: where did u place your multiwordnet.properties can u please the hierarchy

Comment: All the code has been provided as is. Neither the location of files nor the code has been modified.
Looking at the error, it seems that can't parse the number, but the number, as you can see, is correctly written

Comment: I suggest commenting out lines systematically in order to find the invalid line first. Maybe we will be surprised it's not `CACHE_CAPACITY=1000`. Further, you could check if it is a problem only of the last line. In some systems, the "last line" tends to be buggy in so far that it needs a CRLF too, so becoming the second last row. Third, is there any cache that could make disturbing effects?

Comment: What do you suggest for justifying that the code was running two hours ago? I really did nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with `File` in java don't struggle with relative paths. They are quite unpredictable since they depend on the current working directory on which you don't have total control. Use classpath instead, loading the resource using the class loader:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("multiwordnet.properties"));
```

Your problem isn't not being able to parse an integer, but not being able to load your file.

Comment: Ok, I do agree with you, but, supposing that the file path is correct, why isn't able to load the file?

Comment: I think the problem is exactly that the file path is incorrect... You should check your working directory when trying to load the file and see if the path is right. Try `System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: You're welcome folk! May the [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_to_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29) be with you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out for irregular invisible chars, like `<SHIFT>+<SPACE>` or `<CTRL>+<SPACE>` or else, next to `CACHE_CAPACITY=1000`.

Sounds a bit profanatory, but I've often enough stumbled upon such things.

Comment: This was the first thing I checked. Unfortunately,everything is ok with the configuration file, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check for spaces in your properties file or try as below

```
String cacheProp = connectionParameters.getProperty("CACHE_CAPACITY")
//For debug
System.out.println("cacheProp="+cacheProp);
Integer cache = new Integer(cacheProp.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked fine for me i kept the properties file in resources folder(src/main/resources)

```
public static void MysqlDictionary() {
            try {
                Properties p = new Properties();
                p.load(MyTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.properties"));
                String host = p.getProperty("MWN_HOSTNAME");
                String user = p.getProperty("MWN_USER");
                String passwd = p.getProperty("MWN_PASSWD");
                String dbname = p.getProperty("MWN_DB");
                String cache = p.getProperty("CACHE_CAPACITY");
                int i = Integer.parseInt(cache);
                System.out.println(host+"\t"+user+"\t"+passwd+"\t"+dbname+"\t"+i);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```